# Webpack 2: fixing build error on fetch polyfill

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-polyfill

I've a JavaScript ES6 development environment with webpack 2.2.1 where I'm developing an application `package-a`.

I'm also using this environment for managing a development dependency on `package-b` which is defined by using `npm link`.

The environment works well.

Now I need to polyfill the `fetch` API that **is used by package-b**.

So `whatwg-fetch` has ben installed.

The polyfilling way I'm using is the one suggested in this discussion: https://gist.github.com/Couto/b29676dd1ab8714a818f#gistcomment-1584602

So I'm not calling `import 'whatwg-fetch'` on my code but I've this in my webpack configuration:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'Promise': 'es6-promise',
      'fetch': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
      'Headers': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.Headers!whatwg-fetch'
    }),
    ...
```

This always worked well for me, and also works if I use `fetch` from my main (`package-a`) module but as I use fetch in the dependency I get this traceback:

```
ERROR in ../package-b/~/imports-loader?this=>global!../package-b/~/exports-loader?global.fetch!../ecmwf-prwa-editor/~/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js
Module build failed: Error: "...package-b/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js" is not in the SourceMap.
```

Note that the traceback contains ref to the `package-b` *node_modules* directory (where `whatwg-fetch` is installed as a development dependency only as I want to keep in "pure" and without automatically polifyll host env).

Removing the development dependency and removing it from `node_modules` change the traceback:

```
ERROR in ../package-b/src/something/something.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'whatwg-fetch' in '/Users/keul/.../package-b/src/something'
...
```

If I drop this way of polyfilling and simply I put `import 'whatwg-fetch'` on `package-a` all works normally.

Question is: what's happening here? I'm developing a package where the dependency is present, why the polyfill through webpack is failing in this case? There' a way to fix it?